# Bulk add tasks to Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, tasks

Is there a way to bulk-add a list of tasks to Outlook?

If I have a list like the following, can it be used (e.g. copy/pasted) to create a task per line?

```
Task 1
Task 2
Task 3
```

And get the following (in any order):

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Is there a way to bulk-add a list of tasks to Outlook?

You can import tasks from a `.csv` file.

I would suggest the following:

- Export your current tasks as a `.csv` file so you know how the task fields are formatted as csv.

  1. "File" > "Open/Export" > select "Import/Export"
  2. In the "Import and Export Wizard" window, select "Export to a file", then click on "Next".
  3. Select "Comma Separated Values", then click "Next"
  4. In the "Export to a file" dialog, select a name for the csv file, then click "Next"
  5. In the "Export to a file" dialog, check the box for "Export 'Tasks'" from folder:...", then click "Finish".
- Create a new csv file containing the tasks to be added using your favourite editor.
- Import the new task csv file.

Comment: You can simply use `"Subject"` as line 1 header if that is all you have

Comment: Expanding upon what @KCD said, for example, simply enter each task on a new line after `Subject` into a file named Tasks.CSV:  
`Task 1  
Task 2  
Task 3`